# How to change FFT spike to curve

Tags: filter, fft, graph

The first picture is a part of my circuit and the voltage pass through the high filter circuit. The second picture shows an FFT spike which is obtained from the .csv file created by oscilloscope. I want to convert the spike to drawn red curve. (What first comes to my mind is changing filter type or its cut-off frequency)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you applying an input signal? If you're measuring a sine-wave, then that's what you get from the FFT: a spike. If you apply a different signal, you will get another spectrum.

Comment: The circuit looks odd, open end with positive feedback. But the LM358 has bandwidth of 0.7MHz, so it can't possibly generate 90 MHz parasitic oscillations, as FFT shows...

Comment: @AliChen Yup -- no DC negative feedback path.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you might be able to adjust this by changing your simulation time.  As Sven B wrote a sin wave is just a spike, but it looks like you have a sinc convolved with a spike.  And the sinc is clearly too narrow be generated by your filtering circuitry.  So the narrow sinc comes from the long "pulse" you put through the system.  To get a wider sinc, reduce the time of your effective "pulse" by reducing your overall simulation window.

Comment: This is not in simulations. The OP states that real oscilloscope trace was dumped into .csv file and processed by FFT algorithm,  and the result shows massive oscillations at about 90MHz (if the frequency scale is drawn correctly).